# Match Character Whether or Not It Exists in Like Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I need a like expression that will match a character whether or not it exists.  It needs to match the following values:

- `..."value": "123456"...`
- `..."value":  "123456"...`
- `"...value":"123456"...`

This like statement will almost work: `LIKE '%value":%"123456"%'`

But there are values like this one that would also match, but I don't want returned:

- `..."value":"99999", "other":"123456"...`

A regex expression to do what I'm looking to do is `'value": *?"123456"'`.  I need to do this in SQL Server 2008 and I don't believe there is good regex support in that version.  How can I match using a like statement?

Comment: `MyColumn like '%"value":%"123456"%'`?

Comment: That matches all 4 example I gave.  I need something that matches just the first 3.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do, mybe a simple data and desired outputs will help.

Comment: @sami and upvoter. OP is trying to match the word `value` and the word `123456` only if it has a colon and white space in between. If anything else comes between `value` and `123456` then it shouldn't match. The question is pretty clear.

Comment: Perhaps you could grab the substring defined by CharIndex('"value":') to CharIndex('"123456"') + 8. Then check the string length after replacing out the white space to see if it matches an expected length (15.. I think).

Comment: @JNevill You charindex idea was brilliant.  In the end I'm using that to extract my value and then running a compare off of the real values.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the whitespace in your compare with `REPLACE()`:

```
WHERE REPLACE(column,' ','') LIKE '%"value":"123456"%'
```

May need a double replace for tabs:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(column,' ',''),'    ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with [the like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql).  You could exclude ones you could match, like if you want to make sure it just doesn't contain `other`:

```
[field] LIKE '%value":%"123456"%` AND [field] NOT LIKE '%"other"%'
```

Otherwise I think you'd have to do some processing on the string.  You could write a UDF to take the string and parse it to find the value for 'value' and compare based on that:

```
dbo.fn_GetValue([field], 'value') = '123456'
```

The function could find the index of `'"' + @name + '"'`, find the next index of a quote, and the one after that, then get the string between those two quotes and return it.